# How can I load two custom tableview cells for one table view

Tags: ios

I would like to use the two custom tableviewcells(two nib files) like first custom view for first row and second for second row. But the first tableviewcell is not loading. Each row is showing with the second one only. Below is the code I used,

In viewdidload, I have registered like

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCell" bundle:nil];
[self.mainTableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SecondTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
[self.mainTableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 //UITableViewCell *cell;

static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"TableViewCell";
static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"SecondTableViewCell";


if (indexPath == 0) {
   TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        return cell;
} else {
  SecondTableViewCell*  cell = (SecondTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        cell.questionLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",indexPath.row+1];
        //cell.questionName.text = [self.questionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        return cell;
}


return nil;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean if (indexPath.row == 0)?

Comment: yeah I forgot it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try indexpath.row.
If you youse if(indexpath==0), it will not check with the row value.

Answer (score 1):

1) change this line it will work

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) { 
TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        return cell;
}
```

2)Every time it is returning cell with identifier2 because `indexPath` will not be nil

Answer (score 0):

An index path isn't a number.  Testing `if (indexPath == 0)` means "if there is no indexPath".

Try `indexPath.row`.